# Sharepoint List Column Calculation Nested Formula Failing

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-list, formula

I have a column in my Sharepoint list that for some reason doesn't seem to be calculating properly, it does however work in Excel. I am trying to get the result to put a zero if the choice column is "No". However the column is showing the calculated answer as if it has "Yes"(or not "No" for that matter) in it. The Formula is below.

`=IF([Column1]="No",0,IF(ISBLANK([Column3]),NOW()-[Column2],[Column3]-[Column2]))*24`

The "Yes" and "No" are forced choices if that helps

As I say, the formula works in Excel but not in Sharepoint so I don't know where I am going wrong. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use False instead of "No" in the Formula
`=IF(Column1=FALSE,0,IF(ISBLANK(Column3),NOW()-Column2,Column3-Column2))*24`

Comment: Many Thanks Sandro. That sorted it!